# How do I specify the path to the library to run a script from another script?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I need to check the change of one parameter, if it has changed - I need to restart the script.

code:

```
import subprocess, os.path, time

from engine.db_manager import DbManager

DB = DbManager(os.path.abspath(os.path.join('../webserver/db.sqlite3')))

tmbot = None
telegram_config = DB.get_config('telegram')
old_telegram_token = ''

vkbot = None
vk_config = DB.get_config('vk')
old_vk_token = ''


while True:
    telegram_config = DB.get_config('telegram')
    if old_telegram_token != telegram_config['token']:
        if vkbot != None:
            tmbot.terminate()
        tmbot = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'tm/tm_bot.py'])
        old_telegram_token = telegram_config['token']
        print('telegram token was updated')

    vk_config = DB.get_config('vk')
    if old_vk_token != vk_config['token']:
        if vkbot != None:
            vkbot.terminate()
        vkbot = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'vk/vk_bot.py'])
        old_vk_token = vk_config['token']
        print('vk token was updated')

    time.sleep(30)
```

I get errors:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJlxF.png)

Comment: See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) for reasons **not** to do it.

Answer (score 0):

While there might be subtle differences between unix and windows, the straight-up answer is: you can use `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to let python know where to look for libraries.
However, if you use [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), I'd recommend activating it first, or calling the relevant binary instead of setting the environment variable.

Consider this scenario: you have a venv at `/tmp/so_demo/venv`, and you try to run this file:

```
$ cat /tmp/so_demo/myscript.py
import requests
print("great success!")
```

Running the system python interpreter will not find the requests module, and will yield the following error:

```
$ python3 /tmp/so_demo/myscript.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/so_demo/myscript.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

As I have installed `requests` in the venv, if I provide the path to python, it will know where to look:

```
$ PYTHONPATH='/tmp/so_demo/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/' python3 /tmp/so_demo/myscript.py
great success!
```

but using the binary inside the venv is better, as you don't need to be familiar with the internal venv directory paths, and is much more portable (notice that the path I provided earlier depicts the minor version):

```
$ /tmp/so_demo/venv/bin/python /tmp/so_demo/myscript.py
great success!
```